# Calculate Birthdate from an age using y,m,d in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to create a formula to obtain the birth date from an age?

```
Age = 14d, 3m, 55y
Today = 13/01/2021
Birthdate = ?
```

Comment: If you convert the age to days you can just substract it from the today's date. Another option is to use the DATE function and substract the age parts from the date parts (years,months,days). Basically my main issue will be parsing the Age parameter since the format is a bit arbitrary

Comment: I have tried using DATE(YEAR(A1)-55,MONTH(A1)-3,DAY(A1)-14), but can't get it to work. A! is today()

Comment: What did you get ? was there an error or something?  this should work fine

Comment: I just tried it again to show you and it has worked. Very Strange.

Comment: This should be the easiest way to calculate it since you won't have to deal with leap years and number of days in a month

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell E2 (in my example):

```
=A2-(B2*365.25+C2*30.4375+D2)-1
```

see the below screenshot for the whole example:[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a date in **A1** and an age-string in **B1** like:

[image]

First enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function BirthDay(d As Date, age As String) As Date
    Dim v As String, arr, tDate As Date
    
    v = Replace(age, "y", "")
    v = Replace(v, "m,", "")
    v = Replace(v, "d,", "")
    
    arr = Split(v, " ")
    tDate = DateAdd("d", -arr(0), d)
    tDate = DateAdd("m", -arr(1), tDate)
    BirthDay = DateAdd("yyyy", -arr(2), tDate)
    
End Function
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=birthday(A1,B1)
```

Format **C1** as you require.  Here is an example with UK formatting:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To check the answer, we can use the `DATEDIF()` function.  In **D1** enter:

```
=DATEDIF(C1,A1,"y") & " years, " & DATEDIF(C1,A1,"ym") & " months, " & DATEDIF(C1,A1,"md") & " days"
```

[image]

which re-constructs the age-string in **B1**.  30 September 1965 makes sense intuitively:

[image]

*(US format above)*

Comment: Nice work, but there is something's wrong there - I got 29/9/1965 using the date function.

Comment: @DobromirVelev  Our answers differ by a **single day**.  I will re-check my result using the Excel `DATEDIF()` function.

Comment: Found it -  the issue is that you are substracting the days first, then months, then years. The function does it in the reverse order to avoid leap years and months with different lengths eg Dec is 31 days , Sep is 30

Comment: @DobromirVelev  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: well datedif with md is a bit funny (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c), just try substracting in the reverse order to see what I'm talking about

Comment: @DobromirVelev  I agree that `DATEDIF()` is buggy.  I tried starting from *30 September 1965* and working forward in time.  See my last table. *(it is manual without `DATDIF()`)*

Comment: 2020-01-13 - 55 years ->1966-01-13 - 3 months -> 1965-10-13 - 14 days =>1965-09-29. The days subtraction really depends on your current month

Comment: I really don't know which is the correct method of subtracting dates like this, both results are correct - here is a handy date calculator that gets both results https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=13&m1=1&y1=2021&type=sub&ay=55&am=3&aw=&ad=14&rec=

Comment: @DobromirVelev  **your are correct!** ..............the answer is ambiguous...............